# Issues Showing/Hiding ContentControl in Word Online

Tags: office-js

### Desired outcome

What I would like to achieve is to be able to programatically show/hide blocks
of text (single or multiple paragraphs) based upon some logic.

### Attempts

I have attempted to solve this problem in the following ways, each with their
own issues, which I will expand on below.

#### Hidden text

The simplest way is t just turn the "hidden" *paragraph option* on. This would
work great, except that it is not supported in *Word Online*. Man, really?

#### OOXML

The next way is to store the contents of the *Content Control* in an *XML Part*
inside the document, and then restore it later. This works partly, but is an
incredibly flaky experience. The procedure is incredibly slow, and many times it
would just fail silently.

##### Hiding the Content Control

Hiding the Content Control is rather simple, and works fast every time:

```js
/**
 * A helper to store a document setting
 **/
type DocumentSettingSet = <T>(settingName: string, settingValue: T) => void;
const documentSettingSet: DocumentSettingSet = (settingName, settingValue) =>
  Office.context.document.settings.set(settingName, settingValue);

/**
 * Save all document settings to the document
 **/
export type DocumentSettingsSave = () => Promise<void>;
export const documentSettingsSave: DocumentSettingsSave = async () => {
    await Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
};

/**
 * A helper to set an XML Part in the document
 **/
const xmlPartSet = (xml: string): Promise<Office.CustomXmlPart> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Office.context.document.customXmlParts.addAsync(xml, (result) => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        reject(result.error);
        return;
      }
      resolve(result.value);
    });
  });

/**
 * Hide a Content Control, and store its contents for later restoration
 **/
Word.run(async (context) => {
  // Find the Content Control to hide - We can assume I know the ID here
  const contentControl = context.document.contentControls.getById('the-control-id');
  context.load(contentControl, ['appearance', 'tag', 'title']);
  await context.sync();
  // Get the OOXML within the Content Control and store it in a Custom XML Part
  // Store the ID of the Custom XML Part in a Document Setting for later use.
  const xml = contentControl.getRange('Content').getOoxml();
  await context.sync();
  const xmlPart = await xmlPartSet(xml.value);
  documentSettingSet<string>(`block-xml-part-id-${contentControl.tag}`, xmlPart.id);
  await documentSettingsSave();
  // Empty the Content Control and hide the fact that it is a Content Control
  contentControl.cannotEdit = false;
  await context.sync();
  contentControl.appearance = Word.ContentControlAppearance.hidden;
  contentControl.insertText('\u200b', Word.InsertLocation.replace);
  contentControl.cannotEdit = true;
  await context.sync();
});
```

##### Showing the Content Control

Showing the Content Control is where things go wrong. First, it takes incredibly
long, and then once the loader disappears it still takes another minute or more
to actually show. Many times it also does not show and just fails and logs to
the console to refresh the page for the content to show.

```js
/**
 * A helper to get a Document Setting value
 **/
export type DocumentSettingGet = <T>(settingName: string) => T;
export const documentSettingGet: DocumentSettingGet = (settingName) =>
  Office.context.document.settings.get(settingName);

/**
 * A helper to get a Custom XML Part from the document
 **/
export const xmlPartGet = (id: string): Promise<Office.CustomXmlPart | null> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByIdAsync(id, (result) => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        reject(result.error);
        return;
      }
      resolve(result.value);
    });
  });

/**
 * A helper to read the value of a Custom XML Part
 **/
export const xmlPartRead = (
  xmlPart: Office.CustomXmlPart | Office.CustomXmlNode,
): Promise<string> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    xmlPart.getXmlAsync((result) => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        reject(result.error);
        return;
      }
      resolve(result.value);
    });
  });

/**
 * A helper to remove a Custom XML Part from the document
 **/
export const xmlPartRemove = (xmlPart: Office.CustomXmlPart): Promise<void> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    xmlPart.deleteAsync((result) => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        reject(result.error);
        return;
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });

/**
 * Show a Content Control  which was previously hidden (as above)
 **/
Word.run(async (context) => {
  // Find the Content Control to show - We can assume I know the ID here
  const contentControl = context.document.contentControls.getById(contentControlId);
  context.load(contentControl, ['appearance', 'tag', 'title']);
  await context.sync();
  // Get the OOXML to insert into the Content Control
  const xmlPartId = documentSettingGet<string>(`block-xml-part-id-${contentControl.tag}`);
  const xmlPart = await xmlPartGet(xmlPartId);
  if (xmlPart) {
    const xml = await xmlPartRead(xmlPart);
    contentControl.cannotEdit = false;
    await context.sync();
    contentControl.insertOoxml(value, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
    contentControl.appearance = Word.ContentControlAppearance.boundingBox;
    await context.sync();
    // Remove the XML Part now that we're done with it
    await xmlPartRemove(xmlPart);
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you running these methods from a function command on the ribbon or from a task pane?

Comment: Hey @RickKirkham - These are being run from an _Add-In_ in the Task Pane. The _Add-In_ is manually loaded via a `manifest.xml` upload for now.